# Deploying a classic ASP site from IIS 6 (2003 WS) to IIS 7 (WS 2008). Tried Manual deploy and msdeploy

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, web-config

I want to migrate a classic ASP site which contains lots of .asp files and lots and lots of PDFs, docs files. (total size is about 5 GB.) Additionally There are two other dependent websites using same database.

Now, I tried:

1. Manually copying 5 GB to 2008 and then creating a website with asp pool (unmanaged code) and pointing it to physical path.
2. Using web deploy tool. Created zip package at source server, extracted at destination server.

In both cases I had to change Web.config file because it wasn't well formatted. Changing the web.config making conflict in files which are using it.

Now, I am able to see only HTML content and not ASP content in site. With web.config dependancy gone.

How can I make the single web.config file work for all sites?

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question but have you actually enabled Classic ASP on your IIS7 server?  It isn't enabled by default.

Comment: What happens when you request an ASP page? Any errors?

Comment: All ASP, CGI ISAPI are installed and I am getting ASP option in my feature view as well.

Comment: When I run Individual ASP pages. it works.

Comment: My previous classic ASP application has two pages: index.html and index.asp. I am able to see only Html file in IIS 7 after changing config file.

Comment: @john The problem was with application pool. Now i created a tailored application pool, I am able to run my Application.

Comment: ANother issue: My Application consist of two project: one is classic asp and other is aspx project. Both are called from base html page. Now if i call aspx page first, asp page will show connection issue with database (Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle) while if i start my classic asp first, it will connect with Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle  but shows problem with aspx connection (providerName="System.Data.OracleClient") Please assist.

Comment: Probably best to start a new question for the new issue with code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install ASP support for IIS?

[image]

Do you "ASP" feature in Sites?

[image]

Comment: Yes.. ASP, CGI ISAPI all are installed and I am getting ASP option in my IIS feature view.

Comment: Thanks. ANother issue: My Application consist of two project: one is classic asp and other is aspx project. Both are called from base html page. Now if i call aspx page first, asp page will show connection issue with database (Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle) while if i start my classic asp first, it will connect with Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle but shows problem with aspx connection (providerName="System.Data.OracleClient") Please assist.